# access string that is declared in xaml.cs from viewmodel - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can i access to a value of an variable that is declared in xaml.cs (from the viewmodel).

```
String strFileName = path.Text.ToString();
```

Lets say this is in my xaml.cs and i want  to use strFileName in my ViewModel.

how?

thanks in advance

**edit (code):**

im my UserControl (Page1):

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty productsStringProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "productsString", typeof(string), typeof(Page1),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
    {
        PropertyChangedCallback = OnproductsStringChanged,
        BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
    });
    private static void OnproductsStringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    { }

    public static void SetproductsString(UIElement element, String value) { element.SetValue(productsStringProperty, value); }
    public static String GetproductsString(UIElement element) { return (String)element.GetValue(productsStringProperty); }
```

xaml:

```
             views:Page1.productsString="{Binding productsString}"
```

then i call:

```
String paths = products.Text.ToString();
this.SetCurrentValue(productsStringProperty,paths);
```

then im my VM:

```
 private string _products;

    public string Products
    {
        get { return _products; }
        set
        {
            _products = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Products"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: By XAML.cs you mean the view?  The window the viewmodel is the datacontext of?

Comment: yes, i have the view Page1 (UserControl) and the DataContext is my Page1VM

Comment: Adding code would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're new to this stuff, if you already know some or most of this then great, just move on past bits.

The usual way to connect your view and viewmodel together is binding. This should be your first candidate whenever you think of connecting a view to a viewmodel.
To bind you need a dependency property.  They require a dependency object. Your usercontrol is one of these so you can use that.
Occasionally using a dependency object as a viewmodel can be useful, but I assume your vm is going to be a plain class ( poco ).
You can add a dependency property to a view pretty easily. There's a propdp snippet. That would give you a regular dependency property. That would work but setting a binding on them is a bit awkward so I'd probably go with an attached dependency property.
Read up on them a bit. 
I suggest you also experiment a bit with a regular non attached dependency property and see what happens when you do what I suggest with that.

Add your dependency property in the view's code behind.
Here's one I have myself.  This isn't a string because I want to encourage you to explore this yourself rather than paste some solution in. ( And I can just paste in existing code I have this way. )

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDraggingPieceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsDraggingPiece",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MainWindow),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false
      , new PropertyChangedCallback(IsDraggingPieceChanged)
    ));
```

private static void IsDraggingPieceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // I do stuff here
}

public static void SetIsDraggingPiece(UIElement element, bool value)
{
    element.SetValue(IsDraggingPieceProperty, value);
}
public static bool GetIsDraggingPiece(UIElement element)
{
    return (bool)element.GetValue(IsDraggingPieceProperty);
}

Notice that this uses register**Attached**.

You can then bind that in XAML.  In the opening tag of your view you can use the dp:

```
local:MainWindow.IsDraggingPiece="{Binding IsDraggingPiece}"
```

That will then bind to the IsDraggingPiece property I have in my viewmodel.  There are the usual binding options on that like you could make it mode=twoway.  One of the meta options for a dp makes it use twoway by default. Since you're going to set the value on this and you don't want to over write your binding then use either of those approaches to make the binding twoway and harder to over write. If you use setcurrentvalue it won't over write the binding but I prefer to also signal intent by using mode=twoway. And this way it's doubly safe.

You could alternatively define an attached dependency property if you wanted to use this sort of binding in numerous views.

In your code behind you can then set the value on that attached property.  Use setcurrentvalue for this.

```
this.SetCurrentValue(MainWindow.IsDraggingPieceProperty, true);
```

You can either store your variable in the dependency property itself, or some other private variable in your view and set the dp value from there. Which is best depends on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: i think i can quite understand the dependency properties now. the only thing that i dont know is thow to get the value of the dependency property in my vm because i cant call any method.

Comment: The binding binds from the view to a property in your vm. You use the value there. If you need to act when the value changes then make that property a propfull with a full get and set. Put code in the set.

Comment: hey andy, so i tried this code (added into my question) but the string is empty. can u see my mistake

Comment: One thing I see is here this.SetCurrentValue(productsStringProperty,paths); you should have something like Page1. in front of that property. Look at my version.

Comment: You're probably just experimenting here, but if your end aim was to get the text typed into a textbox then you can just bind the Text property to a property on your viewmodel. <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeVMProperty}"

Comment: Hey andy, i think i completely understand dp's now thanks :D. i think it works all fine but the only thing that doesnt is setcurrentvalue. idk why i cant change the value of the dp. the string arrives empty. i even tested it in the xaml.cs with a messagebox - was still empty. do you know why

Comment: Break the problem down and explore what's happening. Put a break point in where you grab the textbox value, your change handler for the dp and your vm property setter. See what you get at each stage and where it's going wrong.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to tell you that it works completely fine now. thank you so much man.